# Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process' when Firebase Admin is imported - NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am having a hard time importing *Firebase Admin* inside of a specific component in a NextJS app.
The basic idea is to show different buttons on the NavBar component depending on the user being signed in or not. In the `firebase-admin.js`, there is a function that verifies the user id token when provided with a valid one. This is how I am importing it:

`import { verifyIdToken } from "../lib/firebase-admin";`

The error returned:

> error - ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:17:0
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

This function works perfectly fine on another page, the index page.
I tried changing most things in NavBar's code, and I am pretty, if not completely, sure that the problem begins with `firebase-admin.js` being imported. I don't know what might be causing it, although I still have a few theories:

1. Maybe NavBar being placed directly in the root page `_app.js` is causing the problem:

```
#The rest of the imports are up here!#
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";
import { AuthProvider } from "../lib/auth";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      #Some code here#
      <AuthProvider>
        <div
          className="page"
        >
          <NavBar /> <--- NavBar here!
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <div className="footer">
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </AuthProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

2. Perhaps it is not possible to call Firebase Admin from a component.

To be honest, none of the theories raised seem plausible enough but I ran out of ideas.

As always, any help and ideas are much appreciated. :)

**EDIT** - Complete code of the `NavBar` component:

```
import { verifyIdToken } from "../lib/firebase-admin";
import nookies from "nookies";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "./Button";
import NavBarLogged from "./NavBarLogged";

const Navbar = ({ uid }) => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  const showButton = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
      setButton(false);
    } else {
      setButton(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    showButton();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", showButton);
  }, []);

  if (uid) return <NavBarLogged />;

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="navbar-container">
          <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
          <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="/" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                <a className="nav-links">Home</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="#" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                <a className="nav-links">O que é Coliving</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="#" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                <a className="nav-links">Sobre a Croosa</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="#" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                <a className="nav-links">Blog</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="#" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                <a className="nav-links-mobile">Sign Up</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {button && (
            <Button
              buttonStyle="btn--outline"
              buttonSize="btn--large"
              href="/logon"
            >
              Entrar
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
    const token = await verifyIdToken(cookies.token);

    const { uid } = token;

    return {
      props: { uid },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    const uid = null;
    return {
      props: { uid },
    };
  }
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: `firebase-admin` is meant to run on a Node.js environment, like API routes and `getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`. It won't work in the browser.

Comment: I intend to call it inside getServerSideProps only, just as I did on the Index page. The problem occurs when I try to import it.

Comment: Just added the rest of the NavBar code to the question. Check out the edit. :)

Comment: [`getServerSideProps` can only be used from pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page-2), not from regular components. It won't have any effect there and the component will still try to load `firebase-admin` in the client, hence the error. You need to move that logic to your page.

Comment: I guess that solves the question. Do you know any way around this problem?